# Getting user to say only the missing word from a phrase

Tags: prompt

I'm working on picture cues for folks who are brain injured.

Some of the words are card to cue with just a photo. (E.g., *pay*)

So I added a sentence hint. But I noticed some folks try to read the whole sentence outloud. (That's not a big deal unless it's hard for them to do).

What I'm thinking I'll try it to highlight the __ and deemphasize the text.
Like this:

[image]

But I thought I'd check for any better options.

Comment: Why is it important that users say only the word and not the sentence? Why not just let them say the whole sentence?

Comment: Visual processing and verbal processing are managed by different bits of the brain.  So doing it this way gives your users 'two hits' at getting the answer.

Comment: I am not sure the example sentence makes it more clear. First I see the picture and think of night, but then I see the word "day" below and have to figure out why it is there.

Comment: @KenMohnkern It would be OK if they are ABLE to read the whole sentence. I just don't want someone to be frustrated if they TRY to read the whole sentence but cannot (whereas maybe they could have said the single word)

Answer (score 2):

You can change your process. I mean if you show the sentence hint along with the image it will be overwhelming for the user as it's too much information at once for him(as you have mentioned they are brain injured) he has no clue what's happening at first. so chances that he is not getting it's a hint for the image.

So show him the image first followed by the sentence hint(have a little delay between two) and a **big question mark** in place of fill in the blank. hence user would know he has to fill in the blanks, so less probability that he would read the sentence out loud.

Answer (score -1):

usage of **Forms with Boxes.**

Usage of such a form simplifies the task of filling the missing word or number. In this way, you can give a hint of how many characters should be filled in the empty boxes. So you can easily tell them that when you have a form with boxes to fill in make sure to write one letter or one number in each box.

[image]

You can start training them by using simple example as the following (Writing dates in boxes ) :[image]